# pipenv shell, does not activate the virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm trying to go to work with pipenv, but I have problems with the launch of the virtual environment.

errors:

```
➜  test_pipenv pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
 . /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_pipenv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
➜  test_pipenv  . /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_pipenv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
cd: **This is not a directory:** /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_pipenv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
```

**or**

```
➜  test_pipenv /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
zsh: **Access denied:** /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
```

**or**

```
➜  test_pipenv source /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-mzRyHdZF/bin/activate
(test_pipenv) ➜  test_pipenv pip freeze  
certifi==2018.10.15
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.7
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
```

I installed the pipenv twice and get the same error:

> sudo pip install pipenv

**and**

> pip install --user pipenv

I get the same error
I use arch linux and zsh

```
.zshrc 
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
PIPENV_SHELL=/use/bin/zsh
export ZSH=/home/user/.oh-my-zsh
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Help me please. Why does not it work **pipenv shell**?

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong in one of your other shell startup scripts (`.profile` or something), if that's really your complete .zshrc. It should not be doing a 'cd' to `.../bin/activate`. Try moving your shell startup scripts out of the way to see if it starts working.

Comment: goto the project folder where Pipfile is, and then just run "pipenv shell"

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
pip uninstall pipenv
```

this will uninstall existing pipenv
after doing that re-install pipenv by doing this:

```
pip install pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

check for permissions on your $HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs directory. If you are not allowed to create files/ directories in there, you cannot start a virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

If you are In **Arch Linux**  switch bash to fish.

Then run :

> pipenv shell

Answer (score -5):

(can't comment so I'll add this as an answer)

Hi,

From what I can tell you are doing all of this in terminal. If you do not have to work with pipenv, then I would recommend using virtualenv.

Install:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create a new virtual env:

```
virtualenv -p python3 your_env_name
```

load virtual env (from path where created file is located in):

```
source your_env_name/bin/activate
```

You can save your packages already installed with pip like this:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then load them in your virtual env (once you have loaded it) like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to go from virtualenv to pipenv

Comment: pipenv uses virtualenv. The env that pipenv creates has an activate you can call just like one created with virtualenv, because it was created with virtualenv.

Comment: doesn't answer the OP's question